# jQuery: Find all tables in a div and reset classes and properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I find all tables inside a div and reset their classes and properties?

My structure is something like this:

```
<body>
    <header/>
    <main>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <div>Some text</div>
            <table cellpadding="2" border="2" class="randomClass">...</table>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <table cellspacing="1" border="1" class="otherClass">...</table>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <div>Some text</div>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer/>
</body>
```

I need to find all tables inside the div with class "content" and remove celpadding, cellborder, border, class etc and set a new clean class, so it would look like this at the end:

```
<body>
    <header/>
    <main>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <div>Some text</div>
            <table class="cleanTable">...</table>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <table class="cleanTable">...</table>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <div>Some text</div>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer/>
</body>
```

I tried fetching all elements and then foreaching them:

```
var content = $(".content");
content.each(function (i, el) {
    console.log(el);
    el.removeClass();
});
```

Although this does find the right elements, it is a giving me strings that I cannot apply methods on:
`jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: el.removeClass is not a function`

I tried making it find itself to get an object, but this seems to do nothing. No errors either:

```
var content = $(".content");
content.each(function (i, el) {
    var table = $('table', this);
    table.removeClass();
    table.addClass('cleanTable');
});
```

Any idea how to make this work?
PS: So far I only tried reseting the class, haven't checked how other properties are reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With JQuery, you can modify multiple elements at once without looping :

```
$(".content table").removeClass().addClass("cleanTable");
```

should do the trick.

To remove attributes, just continue the same way :

```
 $(".content table").removeAttr("border").removeAttr("cellpadding"); //...
```

Comment: And how can I remove the table paremeters?

Comment: This is a little more complicated if you don't know the attributes names beforehand.

Comment: well, the mains are `border`, `cellpadding` and `cellspacing`

Answer (score 1):

try this: you can remove assigned class and add `cleanTable` by iterating over each table inside content div.
you can remove attribute from table. see below code

```
$(function(){
  $(".content table").each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('cleanTable');
      $(this).removeAttr('border');
      $(this).removeAttr('cellpadding');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this in combination with @blue112 answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different and much "rougher" approach and just scrape off everything in the table and rebuild it all with ONE run.

```
$('.content').each(function() {
     $(this).html(($(this).html()).replace(/<table[^>]+>/ig, "<table class='cleanTable'>"));
});
```